# Java: Getting an Exception in Fetching Data from MySql

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I have made a connection class, JForm Class and a Mainclass to initialize main method. I am trying to fetch records from MySql into a program. There are no errors, the program runs fine but it's showing null pointer exception.

Here's the code of Connection to Database Class:

```
package recordmanagementapp;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConnectDB {
Connection conn;
public void ConnectDatabase()
{
try{

     conn= 
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Login? 
 autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "");

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection has been 
  Successfully Created!");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
 {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }

  }
```

This is the function for fetching data from DB:

```
   private void ShowButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
   evt) {
      try{
          ConnectDB c = new ConnectDB();

       Statement s = c.conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from UserLogin");

   while (rs.next())
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString("email") + " 
     and " + rs.getString("password"));

   }
  }
   catch(Exception e)
           {
             e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
           }




     }
```

Comment: Please post the exception/error you are getting. This will help us to figure out where you are wrong.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace/error

Comment: i was getting, Java.Lang.NullPointer Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your database connection variable is null. That's why you get the null pointer exception. You need to initialize the database by calling the `ConnectDatabase()` method

```
ConnectDB db = new ConnectDB();
db.ConnectDatabase();

//rest of the code
```

BTW it is a better practice to use lower case in method's start alphabet. `connectDatabase` instead of `ConnectDatabase`